# iText onchange event not firing

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext, openpdf

I am using OpenPDF (based on iText) to make a simple PDF form with 2 inputs, and what I am trying to accomplish is to automatically copy value of first field into the second field, after the first field is filled. I actually need a field that will automatically add all other fields and display sum, but for the start I wanted to try with a simple example.

I attached an onchange action to a field, which should by my understanding trigger whenever any field changes:

```
TextField name1 = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(100, 800, 200, 830), "idInput1");
PdfFormField field1 = name1.getTextField();
field1.put(PdfName.CO, new PdfNumber(1));
writer.addAnnotation(field1);

TextField name2 = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(100, 700, 200, 730), "idInput2");
PdfFormField field2 = name2.getTextField();
field2.setAdditionalActions(PdfName.C, PdfAction.javaScript("event.change = 123;", writer));
field2.put(PdfName.CO, new PdfNumber(2));
writer.addAnnotation(field2);
```

but, this onchange event never gets triggered. If I change this event to PdfName.K, which is for keystroke, then it will trigger.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please share a sample PDF to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally managed to find what was wrong, so I will post it in case somebody needs it, as I failed to find similar example online.

I had two errors:

1) in JSfunction, instead of **"event.change = 123"** should stand **"event.value = 123"**

2) Every field should be added into writer's Calculation Order, setting only the calculation order number for every field is not enough:

```
writer.addCalculationOrder(field1);
writer.addCalculationOrder(field2);
```